# Meaning of category in MutSigCV

Tags: genomics, cancer, gatk, mutations

I am trying to understand the working of MutSigCV. But I am not sure about some terms used in MAF file format which is ***category***.

According to [MutSigCV](http://software.broadinstitute.org/cancer/software/genepattern/modules/docs/MutSigCV), every mutation can be divided into the following categories:

1. CpG transitions
2. CpG transversions
3. C: G transitions
4. C: G transversions
5. A: T transitions
6. A: T transversions
7. null+indel mutations

I am very much clear about some of this categories like C: G transitions and A: T transitions but for rest, I am unable to make any solid conceptual background. Can anyone suggest me the proper definition of these categories of mutations with proper examples?

Thanks.

---

Definition

MutSig stands for "Mutation Significance" and is defined [here](https://software.broadinstitute.org/cancer/cga/mutsig)

Comment: Did you try asking on the [help forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/genepattern-help)? Or your problem is what is each mutation?

Comment: @Llopis: Not yet. I even didn't know about that. I know only GATK forum and this website. I have googled these terms extensively but didn't get even proper definitions. That's why I started the bounty on this question.

Comment: CpG transversions are the same as C: G transversions, except that they are followed by a G which means they are potential targets for DNA methylation. Methylcytosine can undergo deamination to Thymine, which makes them mutation hotspots

Comment: indel = insertion/deletion. I have no idea what null means in this context

Comment: @heathobrien Those comments are an answer! With a link to a source you could get the bounty